# Composer detected issues in your platform - cpanel fatal error

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, cpanel

I tried to deploy laravel 8 in the Cpanel of Hostgator and  Imported database and all the files on the domain folder. while running the project it shows the error.

> Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.3.0". You are running 7.1.14. in /home1/genetco/laravel.oaccoman.com/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24

Comment: try upgrading php version in shared hosting to 7.3.0 or php 8

Comment: it's already in 7.3 still the error comes.

Comment: try once upgrading to php 8

Comment: Cpanel there is no option to upgrade to php8

Comment: try once in composer json  "php": "^7.1|^7.3|^8.0",

Comment: in composer.json its mentioned "php": "^7.3|^8.0", still the error happens

Comment: Is there anything unclear about the given error message? What have you tried to resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change version of the domain from cpanel. Laravel required more than 7.3 version.
I am facing same issue. Resolve from capnel using multiphp option.

Change version to 7.3

See error : You are running 7.1.14

Comment: The version is already in 7.3. Still shows the error

Comment: But your error show : you are running 7.1

Comment: Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.3.0". You are running 7.1.14. in /home1/genetco/laravel.oaccoman.com/vendor/composer

Comment: I changed the PHP version of the particular domain and it worked. thanks